# Sum values in column from previous rows, that fall within a certain time period, and share a unique identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the columns: DATE, INDIVIDUAL_ID, CONDITION_FLAG. Each row represents an individual at a particular date. Each individual can appear at more than one date instance. The CONDITION_FLAG is either a 0, for condition not met, or a 1 for condition met.

I would like to count the number of 1s in the CONDITION_FLAG column, for that row's INDIVIDUAL_ID, that occurred between the date of a row and 60 days before that date (inclusive).

Please see the following example:

```
SELECT DATE
  , INDIVIDUAL_ID
  , CONDITION_FLAG

FROM ORIGINAL_TABLE
;

-- ORIGINAL TABLE:
---------------------------------------------
 DATE       INDIVIDUAL_ID    CONDITION_FLAG
---------------------------------------------
 15/07/19              01               0
 12/07/19              01               1
 01/07/19              01               1
 30/06/19              01               1
 15/07/19              02               1
 11/07/19              02               0
 29/06/19              02               1
 14/07/19              03               0
 02/07/19              03               1
 30/06/19              03               0
 28/06/19              01               0
---------------------------------------------
```

What do I have to add to the query above to create the PREV_CONDITION_COUNT column as shown below?

```
-- DESIRED TABLE:
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 DATE       INDIVIDUAL_ID    CONDITION_FLAG    PREV_CONDITION_COUNT 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 15/07/19              01               0                         3
 12/07/19              01               1                         3
 01/07/19              01               1                         2
 30/06/19              01               1                         1
 15/07/19              02               1                         2
 11/07/19              02               0                         1
 29/06/19              02               1                         1
 14/07/19              03               0                         1
 02/07/19              03               1                         1
 30/06/19              03               0                         0
 28/06/19              01               0                         0
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

All help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a windowed analytic function to do it in a single table scan (without any joins or needing a correlated sub-query):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ORIGINAL_TABLE (DATE1, INDIVIDUAL_ID, CONDITION_FLAG ) AS
  SELECT DATE '2019-07-15', '01', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2019-07-12', '01', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2019-07-01', '01', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2019-06-30', '01', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2019-07-15', '02', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2019-07-11', '02', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2019-06-29', '02', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2019-07-14', '03', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2019-07-02', '03', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2019-06-30', '03', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2019-06-28', '01', 0 FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       SUM( CONDITION_FLAG ) OVER (
         PARTITION BY INDIVIDUAL_ID
         ORDER BY DATE1
         RANGE BETWEEN 60 PRECEDING AND 0 PRECEDING
       ) PREV_CONDITION_COUNT
FROM   ORIGINAL_TABLE t
ORDER BY INDIVIDUAL_ID, DATE1 DESC
```

**Output**:

> ```
> DATE1     | INDIVIDUAL_ID | CONDITION_FLAG | PREV_CONDITION_COUNT
> :-------- | :------------ | -------------: | -------------------:
> 15-JUL-19 | 01            |              0 |                    3
> 12-JUL-19 | 01            |              1 |                    3
> 01-JUL-19 | 01            |              1 |                    2
> 30-JUN-19 | 01            |              1 |                    1
> 28-JUN-19 | 01            |              0 |                    0
> 15-JUL-19 | 02            |              1 |                    2
> 11-JUL-19 | 02            |              0 |                    1
> 29-JUN-19 | 02            |              1 |                    1
> 14-JUL-19 | 03            |              0 |                    1
> 02-JUL-19 | 03            |              1 |                    1
> 30-JUN-19 | 03            |              0 |                    0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=876f334d2b6e7463928423eafde01b14)*

Comment: This is really nice - exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following self join for it:

```
SELECT
    OT1.DATE1,
    OT1.INDIVIDUAL_ID,
    OT1.CONDITION_FLAG,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN OT2.DATE1 BETWEEN OT1.DATE1 - 60 AND OT1.DATE1 THEN OT2.CONDITION_FLAG
    END) AS P
FROM
    ORIGINAL_TABLE OT1
    JOIN ORIGINAL_TABLE OT2 ON ( OT1.INDIVIDUAL_ID = OT2.INDIVIDUAL_ID )
GROUP BY
    OT1.DATE1,
    OT1.INDIVIDUAL_ID,
    OT1.CONDITION_FLAG;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=510e005868747b348a4094a45089988d)

-- In the demo, You can ignore ID column as it was just used to give you output in order defined in the question

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Another option: a correlated subquery:

```
SQL> with test (cdate, individual_id, conditional_flag) as
  2    (select date '2019-07-15', '01', 0 from dual union all
  3     select date '2019-07-12', '01', 1 from dual union all
  4     select date '2019-07-01', '01', 1 from dual union all
  5     select date '2019-06-30', '01', 1 from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select date '2019-07-15', '02', 1 from dual union all
  8     select date '2019-07-11', '02', 0 from dual union all
  9     select date '2019-06-29', '02', 1 from dual union all
 10     --
 11     select date '2019-07-14', '03', 0 from dual union all
 12     select date '2019-07-02', '03', 1 from dual union all
 13     select date '2019-06-30', '03', 0 from dual union all
 14     --
 15     select date '2019-06-28', '01', 0 from dual
 16    )
 17  select t.cdate,
 18         t.individual_id,
 19         t.conditional_flag,
 20         --
 21         (select count(*)
 22          from test t1
 23          where t1.individual_id = t.individual_id
 24            and t1.conditional_flag = 1
 25            and t1.cdate between t.cdate - 60 and t.cdate
 26         ) prev_condition_count
 27   from test t
 28  order by t.individual_id,
 29           t.cdate desc;

CDATE      IN CONDITIONAL_FLAG PREV_CONDITION_COUNT
---------- -- ---------------- --------------------
15/07/2019 01                0                    3
12/07/2019 01                1                    3
01/07/2019 01                1                    2
30/06/2019 01                1                    1
28/06/2019 01                0                    0
15/07/2019 02                1                    2
11/07/2019 02                0                    1
29/06/2019 02                1                    1
14/07/2019 03                0                    1
02/07/2019 03                1                    1
30/06/2019 03                0                    0

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```